Не отображаются файлы с точкой VScode с расширением SFTP
Везде поискал не нашел ответа. Почему расширения на sftp перестало отображать скрытые файлы. На картинке в папке templates/ есть еще .default Но его не видно. Использую natizyskunk.sftp-1.16.3

